# Showing a lock screen image using MPNowPlayingInfoCenter doesn't work

Tags: swift, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I have the following code and is working for me  but it can only currently show artist and song :

```
let mpic = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter()

mpic.nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:songs[currentAudioIndex].songName,
                        MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:songs[currentAudioIndex].artistName]
```

I tried also setting the picture with the following code but it isn't working :

```
mpic.nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:songs[currentAudioIndex].songName,
                    MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:songs[currentAudioIndex].artistName,
                    MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork:songs[currentAudioIndex].songImage]
```

SongImage is of type  UIImage.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work ? Any exceptions, error messages ?

Answer (score 13):

Never mind I figured out.

If anyone want to learn you have to 
do the following

```
    let mpic = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter()
```

//  initialize an instance of  MPMediaItemArtWork with a UIImage

```
    var albumArtWork = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: songs[currentAudioIndex].songImage)
```

// Then assign it to the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter

```
    mpic.nowPlayingInfo = [
        MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:songs[currentAudioIndex].songName,
        MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:songs[currentAudioIndex].artistName,
        MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork:albumArtWork

    ]
```

Hope this helps anyone who is also struggling with this.

Thanks

Comment: Correct. I was just going to tell you this! Good research. Notice how posting causes you to figure it out for yourself. Next time, save bandwidth and use the "rubber duck". :)

Answer (score -1):

```
                MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : AudioCenter.sharedInstnce.currentReciter().name,
                                                                     MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : AudioCenter.sharedInstnce.currentSurah()!.name,
                                                                     MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork:MPMediaItemArtwork(image: UIImage(named: "Logo")!)]
```